# Proper software writing in c

Tags: c, malloc, exit

I work with memory allocation and suppose the allocation failed. 
Do I have to free all the memory in the program before I exit ? 
Is this really necessary ?
Can exit() be enough ?

And if I do need to free all the memory in the program, suppose I have large program with a lot of information in it. How can I manage to  do that?

Comment: When you exit, everything is freed automatically.

Answer (score 0):

In most operating systems all memory owned by process is freed upon exit of that process.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I have to free all the memory in the program before I exit ? Is
>   this really necessary ? Can exit() be enough ?

Only you need to `free()` the memory which was successfully allocated.

`free()` takes pointer which was returned by `malloc()` `realloc()` and `calloc()` so you need to pass this pointer to `free()` if this is NULL then no operation will be done by `free()` so no need to worry about failed allocation.

Yes `exit()` is enough because when you exit all the allocated memory is freed automatically in many operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that depends.

If you want to **continue** after certain allocation has been failed, at the end [or after the memory allocation is not used anymore, whichever is earlier], you've to free() the successfully allocated memory.

OTOH, if you're taking the *hard-way*, making the application to **exit** straightaway after an allocation failure, then you can avoid the free-ing part.